# asp.net - Show popup from popup window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my asp.net application, one of the web page has a small popup(say PopUp1) containing a hyperlink. Now when user clicks this link, I need to open another popup(say PopUp2) but in Parent Window that hosts the origional PopUp1. Also, FYI, the PopUp2 that I want to show is currently a user control which I have declared in PopUp1.

If I call below script from PopUp1,

```
PopUp2.cs

    public void ShowEmailPreviewPopup()
    {            
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(ctlEmailPreviewUpdatePanel,
                            ctlEmailPreviewUpdatePanel.GetType(),
                            "ShowEmailPreviewPopup",
                            "EmailPreviewPopup.Show();",
                            true);
        ctlEmailPreviewUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

it displays the user control in PopUp1 window, which I don't want.
How can I modify the script so that it opens PopUp2 in parent window of PopUp1?

Or any other ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a different window name for popup 2 so the first popup window isn't reused? FYI popups are usually a bad idea (blockers and such) - If you can I'd change the code to use a DHTML dialog such as the jQuery UI dialog http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/